# React-native compatibility with React

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How can I check for each version of `react-native` to which versions of `react` is it compatible with?

I could not find that information in the official docs.

The best I could do is to open `package.json` in `node_modules/react-native` and check the `peerDependencies` section.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned the solution yourself, I don't think there's a better way than looking at the source and seeing what version it requires as a peer dependency.

If you need a shortcut to each versions package.json go to the github repo and select the stable branch of the version you want.

The URL will then look like this and you can just insert the version you need:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0.62-stable/package.json

Comment: I was hoping for some range of compatibility.
I have no need to automate it; a manual check is well enough.
Thanks